# How to pass a variable to another JSP page?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am unfamiliar with jQuery and would like to know the proper way to pass a value to a different JSP. For example, given the code below:

```
function editURL() {
  var x = "<%=nd.getNodedesc()%>"
  $('body').load('editUrl.jsp', {
    x: 560,
    y: 100,
    height: 450,
    width: 551,
    title: "Edit:Advance configuration",
    skinMode: 'dialog',
    iframe: true,
    url: "editUrl.jsp",
    data: {
      filename: x
    },
    offResize: true,
    offMove: true,
    onTitle: false,
    offBottom: true
});
```

I want to get the value `nd.getNodedesc()` which returns a file name and store it in `var x`. Then, I want to load `editUrl.jsp` and pass the data to the new JSP page.

The editUrl.jsp:

```
<%
  // get the values of filename and URL link
  String files = request.getParameter("filename");
%>

<body>
  File Name: <input type="text" name="Filename" value="<%=files%>" readonly><br><br>
```

From there, I will get parameter from `filename` and pass it on. However, it seems that it returns null to the text name so I must have done something wrong.

I couldn't find the problem but what was my mistake here?

Edit:

Tried changing the JS variable to `var x="test121212";` still passes null value to the new JSP page. Still no clue what went wrong.

Comment: Starting with the basics, are you sure that `x` in your JS code has a value?

Comment: From my debugging, yes it appears it passed the value to x.